# Delete line end with specific text or word - in Perl script

Tags: regex, perl

I want to delete line from a text file that contain word or letter "com-" only, i.e that line end with com- to be removed
The below script it removes only com-
Could you please help?

```
open my $input, '<', 'inputfile.txt' or die "$!";
open my $out, '>',   'output.txt' or die $!;
while (<$input>){
    chomp;
    s/com-//g;
    print $out "$_\n";
}
close($input);
close($out);
```

My inputfile.txt

```
10.22.10.12   com-sys28598001
10.21.19.2    com-
10.21.23.3    com-
3.8.3.13      com-
10.22.51.11   com-sys28019338
10.22.7.13    com-
10.22.64.3    com-sts28553063
10.24.18.21   com-sts29290004
10.24.14.24   com-sys24887111
```

desire output.txt

```
10.22.10.12   com-sys28598001
10.22.51.11   com-sys28019338
10.22.64.3    com-sts28553063
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just output the lines that do not end with `com-`.

```
while (<$input>){
    chomp;
    print $out "$_\n" unless /com-$/;
}
```

`/com-$/` matches only when the string ends with `com-`.

A one liner

```
cat inputfile.txt | perl -e "while(<>) { print unless /com-$/}"
```

Or

```
perl -ne "print unless /com-$/" < inputfile.txt
```